# Python IDE with auto completion

Tags: python, ide

please advise me some good Python IDE, I was using netbeans but it does not have suitable code completion (when I press "." it gives me methods of all classes of python. It would be nice if netbeans would work as for ex. for PHP..

Thank you.

Comment: A good Python IDE would be listed here: [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, many IDEs now come with pretty good code completion. Eclipse with pydev is nice, or you can get aptana studio 3 to perform similar to it.
Theres also jetbrain's PyCharm, if you don't mind paying for a licence (they do give a trial version too if you want to test it before buying). There are a lot of such IDEs, guess you have to try them out to see which suits your code completion tastes better.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse with Pydev

nothing better out there

Answer (score 2):

[Pytools](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) should add intellisense for python to visual studio if you are developing on windows. I have not tried it myself so I don't know how good it works.

Comment: Pytools is pretty awesome. It's my new favorite python IDE.  Debugging works like C# which is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

I have also been searching for a good IDE for Python development. I tried using Emacs and [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) but finally settled for [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). It does a really good job at auto completing the code and I find it to be worth the money.

Depending on the type of development you do, you could get a discounted or even a free license.

Answer (score 1):

Try Geany and Ctrl+Enter. Foo bar <= wrote this because SO said answer was to short ;)

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm for pay or Komodo Edit for free.

Answer (score 0):

[Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) has since long time an excellent Python support

Answer (score 0):

I found the below links very helpful in deciding the python IDE. They provide a lot of insight into the features with respect to all the relevant IDEs. It looks like most of them have auto-code completion feature as per these links. Since I have been using eclipse and VS Code all my life, I stick with Pydev or VS Code, yes will need some plugins to install. Pycharm has lot of features, if you can afford paying some money. I also found intelliJ also supports a lot of features.

[What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments